# redirect all subdomain and send request file with get

Tags: php, .htaccess

how i can redirect all subdomain **without change url**

aslo send **subdomain** and **request file** with **GET** method to index.php file,
with .htaccess
for example

http://testsubdomain.mysite.ir/test.php

redirect to

http://mysite.ir/users/index.php?domain=testsubdomain&file=test.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite. Example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /testsubdomain/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$  http://mysite.ir/users/index.php?domain=testsubdomain&file=$1.php
```

Details here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: it work only for testsubdomain , i want to work for every subdomain request

Comment: Did you check the documentation? Have a look at `RewriteCond`.

Comment: yes , but i dont understand i have this code

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mysite\.ir [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php?domain=%1&name= [L]
its work , but i dont know how also get file request

Comment: Not sure what "how also get file request" means, but in the RewriteRule, you forgot to pass the "file" value: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?domain=%1&name=$1 [L]`